# Формат "Общий" в excel-функции ТЕКСТ

Tags: excel, русификация

Помогите пожалуйста перевести формулу на русский язык. Я придумал формулу, которая отличает ноль, пусто и не ноль не пусто, для того чтобы отображать пользователям ошибки при заполнении отчёта, но она не работает в русском excel'е, только в таком, который понимает по английски (английского офиса у меня нет, но она работает в WPS-офисе)

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕСЛИ(ЕПУСТО(B2);"";ТЕКСТ(B2;"General"))="";"Тут пусто";ЕСЛИ(ЕСЛИ(ЕПУСТО(B2);"";ТЕКСТ(B2;"General"))="0";"Тут ноль";"Тут не ноль и не пусто"))
```

Смысл в том что ТЕКСТ переводит содержимое ячейки (каким бы оно ни было) в строку и тогда проверка пусто=ноль выдаёт ЛОЖЬ, тогда как при обычном сравнении выдаётся ИСТИНА.

Вот таблица с работой формулы, в первом столбце - моя формула, во втором клеточки которые проверяются на пустоту, нули и не пустоту, в третьем я показал что в первой ячейке просто пусто, а во второй формулой написана пустая строка, в третьей ноль, в четвёртой текстовый ноль (это разные совершенно вещи))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал =ТЕКСТ(B2;"General") - выдаёт #ЗНАЧ!

Пробовал =ТЕКСТ(B2;"Общий") - выдаёт "Общий"

В принципе я придумал аналогичную функцию:

```
=ЕСЛИ(И(ЕПУСТО(B2)=ИСТИНА;(0=B2)=ИСТИНА;(""=B2)=ИСТИНА);"Тут пусто";ЕСЛИ(И(ЕПУСТО(B2)=ЛОЖЬ;(0=B2)=ЛОЖЬ;(""=B2)=ИСТИНА);"Тут пустая строка";ЕСЛИ(И(ЕПУСТО(B2)=ЛОЖЬ;(0=B2)=ИСТИНА;(""=B2)=ЛОЖЬ);"Тут ноль";ЕСЛИ(И(ЕПУСТО(B2)=ЛОЖЬ;(0=B2)=ЛОЖЬ;(""=B2)=ЛОЖЬ);"Тут не ноль и не пусто";0))))
```

Но её же невозможно использовать несколько раз в более сложной функции(((

Помогите сделать перевод в формат Общий при помощи функции ТЕКСТ или помогите придумать другую формулу, только короткую, пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто проверяйте значение ячейки `=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(ЕПУСТО(B2);B2="");"Тут пусто";ЕСЛИ(B2=0;"Тут ноль";"Тут не ноль и не пусто"))`, а функция `ТЕКСТ()` здесь не нужна

Comment: Я не очень понял, что вам нужно. Затабулируйте, пожалуйста, требуемую функцию (аргумент-значение), а мы подумаем, как это реализовать.

Comment: Используйте функцию ЯЧЕЙКА (=ЯЧЕЙКА("формат";A1)) для того, чтобы узнать коды форматов.

Comment: Ваша формула работает и в русской локали Excel-2010... Но очень уж громоздкая :)  Возможно, смотреть нужно в другом направлении? Перевести в формат Общий. Значит, это для чего-то нужно. Какова конечная цель задачи?

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA вот это в точку, нужно начитать с конечной цели. А то обычно получается проблема XY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По методу дедукции сам нашёл ответ)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И слегка укоротил формулу.

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕСЛИ(ЕПУСТО(B2);"";ТЕКСТ(B2;"Основной"))="";"Тут пусто";ЕСЛИ(ТЕКСТ(B2;"Основной")="0";"Тут ноль";"Тут не ноль и не пусто"))
```

Comment: Так и не понял. зачем цепляться за формат ячейки? Чем не подошли решения в ответе с тремя формулами?

Answer (score 0):

Не забывайте про гибкое и эффективное средство, к которому вы можете прибегнуть: функции, определяемые пользователем.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Option Explicit

Public Function СъедобноеНесъедобное(Ref As Range) As Variant
  Dim r As Variant
  r = False ' здесь ваш код
  СъедобноеНесъедобное = r
End Function
```

Например, вы можете реализовать следующую функцию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Option Explicit

Public Function СъедобноеНесъедобное(Ref As Range) As Variant
  Dim r As Variant
  If Ref.Count > 1 Then
    r = CVErr(xlErrNA)
  ElseIf IsEmpty(Ref) Then
    r = -1
  ElseIf IsNumeric(Ref) Then
    If Ref = 0 Then
      r = 0
    Else
      r = 1
    End If
  ElseIf Ref = "" Then
    r = 2
  Else
    r = 3
  End If
  СъедобноеНесъедобное = r
End Function
```

Вы можете запрограммировать любой анализ и любые возвращаемые значения, в том числе и массивы, под вашу задачу.

Comment: "Гибкое и эффективное" - да, но есть большой минус - UDF, используемые в формулах листа, летучи, т.е. имеют нехорошую привычку пересчитываться при любом чихе на листе. Их наличие  может серьезно тормозить работу с книгой (в зависимости от сложности вычислений и количества формул). При статичных данных функции пользователя лучше вызывать из VBA,

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA последнее время сделал несколько таких функций и проверял их работу. Они пересчитываются только если меняются их аргументы. Excel 365.

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA кстати, на днях сделал интересную штуку с автофильтром https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77205829/formula-to-sum-the-values-of-a-column-based-on-multiple-criteria/77206195#77206195

Comment: В  Excel 365 летучесть не проверял )

Comment: Как дела? Может, есть вопросы?

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA вы про https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133230)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue это знаете?

Comment: Это поздние доработки. Я не слежу за изменениями после версии 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, использование формата здесь лишнее и задача - определить, ячейка пустая, содержит ноль или другое значение:

```
 =ЕСЛИ(B2="";"пусто";ЕСЛИ(B2=0;"ноль";"знач<>0"))
```

Для разделения пустой ячейки и ячейки с наличием строки нулевой длины добавим еще одну проверку:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕПУСТО(B2);"пусто";ЕСЛИ(B2="";"длина0";ЕСЛИ(B2=0;"ноль";"длина>0")))
```

Ныряем глубже - определяем, в ячейке число или текст:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕПУСТО(B2);"пусто";ЕСЛИ(B2="";"длина0";ЕСЛИ(B2=0;"ноль";ЕСЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(B2);"число";"длина>0"))))
```

Нужно понимать, что число в текстовом формате ("0", "123") будет воспринято как текст и для обработки таких вариантов нужны дополнительные проверки. Но правильнее хранить данные в их родных форматах, это застрахует от лишней головной боли.